# WinAPI: запуск программы под текущим интерактивным пользователем

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7, windows-xp

Операционки: Windows XP и Windows 7.

Нужно из под программы, которая будет работать из под планировщика из под системной учетной записи, запускать другие процессы, которые должны будут работать уже под текущей интерактивной сессией (если таковая на тот момент будет).

Как сделать подобную программу? Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону рыть, что почитать по этому поводу (для обоих операционок)???

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно, что бы работало под разными осями, тогда нужно действовать через "посредника" - ещё одно приложение, которое будет добавлено каждому пользователю в автозагрузку. С основной программой будет связываться посредством tcp/ipc и получать от нее команды, в том числе, запустить другую. Так действуют многие "большие" программы, например, антивирусы.